# How to use getScaleController() and PinchGesture?

Tags: java, android, arcore

I am looking for realtime scaling of objects/models in ARcore. I found that it can be done using
`getScaleController()` and `PinchGesture` class. I have a `TransformableNode` and I want to use the above method and class for achieving realtime scalling of model to update model's dimensions at runtime.
I checked the documentation already, but it didn't help me.

here is my code

```
TransformableNode node = 
                    new TransformableNode(arFragment.getTransformationSystem());
node.setParent(anchorNode);
node.setRenderable(modelRenderable);
node.select();
        
/* After this I want to use PinchGester or PinchGestureListener and 
node.getScaleController() to achieve my goal */
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you help me answer this question or you can pass this question to someone who can answer this asap. @a_local_nobody

Comment: if i could answer your question, I would :) we're all just here on our own time, so your question will find an answer at its own time and pace